# Installed Debian on a PC, now cannot boot to anything else

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, debian

I installed Debian (6.07) on a PC.  I wanted to install Ubuntu (12.10) after, but I could not boot to CD after Debian was installed.  In fact no bootable disk(CD or floppy) would load once Debian was installed.

I can boot to all of these media if I unplug the HDD.

What's going on here?

Comment: Sounds like you have to change the boot order in BIOS

Comment: Boot order is Floppy/cd/hdd  Even if I disable the hdd boot order, it still hands and never loads the bootable media.  If I physically unplugged the hdd data cable (ide) it boots into the media just fine.  If I plug the hdd back in, even having it not bootable, the boot hangs after the bios post.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a faulty/corrupted hard drive. Try removing the drive, booting into a live cd, then reconnecting the drive. Then use `fsck` to check the hard drive. If that does not work, you could try making a new partition table using `fdisk` or similar tools.

It could also be your BIOS configuration. Check that and make sure your removable media/cd drive is before your hard drive.

EDIT: Ignore that last paragraph as I just saw the comments to the question.

Comment: How do I load a disk utility if I cannot get it to boot into another os other than debian?

Comment: It seems my only recourse is to wipe the drive and start over.

Comment: As I stated remove the hard drive then boot into cd then reconnect the drive

Comment: That's what I am doing now - wiping and starting over with Ubuntu.  I just really want to know why the debian install prevented me from booting into another os?

Comment: Maybe the install corrupted your hard drive, coupled with a possibly buggy bios, caused external boot methods to be disabled.

Comment: Possible, very strange for sure.  Appreciate your help and advise.

Comment: Hope it helps :)